# Can I get rid of browser asking permissions after building with 'ionic cordova build browser'?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I want to build my Hybrid web app with `ionic cordova build browser`, the browser asks for permissions (in this case the permission to store files). Do I need those cordova based permissions on browser and if not, is there a way to get rid of them?

[image]